# curl url failed: Connection reset by peer

Tags: nginx

I have a pac file, which is hosted in my nginx server, suppose the url of it is *http://xxx.xx/my.pac*, the problem is when I `wget http://xxx.xx/my.pac` , often got error, the detail is like below:

> ```
> --2016-07-29 22:45:14--  http://xxx.xx/my.pac
> ```
>
> Resolving xxx.xx... 109.28.49.32
>   Connecting to xxx.xx|109.28.49.32|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>   Length: 59903 (58K) [application/octet-stream]
>   Saving to: 'my.pac'
>
> my.pac              22%[==>              ]  13.45K  --.-KB/s    in 0s
>
> 2016-07-29 22:45:15 (85.9 MB/s) - Read error at byte 13776/59903
>   (Connection reset by peer). Retrying.
>
> --2016-07-29 22:45:16--  (try: 2)  http://xxx.xx/my.pac Connecting to xxx.xx|109.28.49.32|:80... failed: Connection reset by peer.
>   Resolving xxx.xx... 109.28.49.32

And below is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxx.xx;
    access_log  /home/tom/.log/access.log;
    error_log  /home/tom/.log/error.log;

    location / {
        root   /home/tom/www;
        index  index.html;
   }
}
```

And the my.pac file is in the path of `/home/tom/www/`

I think the problem maybe caused by my nginx conf file, but I cannot found the answer by google.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is the file perhaps corrupt? The fact that you've received a 200 response and the download initiated says that your config is fine (the exception being that if you've explicitly defined your connection timeout to be extremely small). If the file isn't corrupted, check your timeout settings in `nginx.conf`, enable `gzip` compression (just for size purposes) and check that `sendfile` is on.

Comment: Thanks at first, I can confirm the problem is caused by my nginx conf file, but I'm a newbie for nginx, I'll start to learn something about nginx, Thanks for your remind again!

Comment: No problem, good luck!